# What is this weird margin from?

Tags: css, firebug, margin

The home page does not have any space above the div#site_wrap that everything is inside of but the portfolio page has a big top margin which doesn't show up anywhere in firebug.

reference: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/?page_id=91

Comment: In chrome it loooks good

Comment: @Mr.Alien is right. Works in chrome, only Firefox gives margin.

Comment: `.margin_top40, .mt40` seems to be causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it where's the issue here...

It's this line

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

In this section

```
<div class="announcement_wrapper">
    <div class="announcement">
        <div class="announcement_message"><p>This is an announcement box! Click close to remove it after you've read it.</p></div>
        <div class="close_announcement"><p>close x</p></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing that `<div>` makes the whole announcement go away. (not really, but you cant see it). However, in addition to this, you can add `overflow: hidden;` to `.announcement {}`, and it works fine.

Comment: @MiniGod Ya it's an issue with your floats, I can see the text is still there, you updated your page

Comment: yeah i see it.  i just removed the clear and added a width of 920px to the announcement and it works.  thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
add `margin-top: -40px;` to `.block_wrapper {}`

Comment: this does not support in IE 8 and earlier.